# How to submit hidden form with omniauth in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4.2, omniauth-facebook, omniauth-google-oauth2

I have integrated google and facebook omniauth in my rails application. The signup and signin works great. But, I also have a form which should be submitted along with omniauth, so that I can access the form content as parameters.

This is the piece of code:

```
%section#hero.hero-blk
.container
  .intro.text-center
    %h1 Ask Question Instantly
    %h3.hero-tagline Ask anonymously anytime
  .row
    .col-md-6
      .ask-question
        %h2.text-center Talk to us
        %form{method: 'post', action: new_forward_questions_path}
          =hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token
          %textarea.form-control{:autofocus => "", :cols => "20", :id => "question-content", :name => "content", :placeholder => "Describe your question on relationship, marriage. Please type atleast 50 characters", :rows => "7"}
          %div#chars-left
          %input{type: 'hidden', name: 'source', value: 'home'}
          .text-center
            %button#ask-button-index.glow-button.btn.btn-primary{type: 'submit'}
              %img{:alt => "", :src => image_path("incognito-new.svg")}/
              Ask Anonymously

.modal-body
    #dialog-loading-icon.collapse
      %p
        Please wait, submitting your question
      =image_tag "ripple.gif"
    = simple_form_for @question do |f|
      = f.input :content, as: :hidden, input_html: {id: 'hidden_question_content'}
      - if current_user.nil? or current_user.asker.nil? or current_user.asker.new_record?
        .social-sign-in.visitor-oauth.text-center
          = link_to "Sign up with Gmail", user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path(@question), class: "zocial gmail"
          = link_to "Sign up with Facebook", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, class: "zocial facebook"
```

Below is the screenshot of html generated As you can see the modal form gets populated with "Oauth Oauth Oauth" This is the content which I am writing inside the textarea and when I click on the button the modal pops up and has the same content I typed:
[image: Html Generated]

I have tried passing @question here but nothing gets passed. In controller I am trying to access the params through **request.env["omniauth.params"]** but it is always blank.

How can I access or pass this content parameter to omniauth and access it in controller?

Comment: `@question` is an instance of a new record or an existing record

Comment: @Pavan New record

Comment: If its new record, then the value of `content` will always be nil.Then there is no point in making it as hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a *form* here since the `content` is a *hidden input*. You can pass it as *extra params* to `link_to` like below

```
= link_to "Sign up with Gmail", user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path(content: "Your desired value"), class: "zocial gmail"
```

and look for `content` in `request.env["omniauth.params"]`

**Update:**

The only way I can think of by appending the value of content to the url on a click event using Javascript of Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".gmail, .facebook").click(function(){
    var hidden_content = $("#hidden_question_content").val();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = "url?content="+hidden_content;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please see my edit. The content is pre filled in the modal which comes from the content I type inside textarea

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal I've updated my answer. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Is there a way I can use this :content from  f.input :content, as: :hidden, input_html: {id: 'hidden_question_content'}? Because this has the value I need. Otherwise I will try your javascript way

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal I can't think of any. I will post if I come up with anything. Meanwhile try my updated answer :)

Comment: .click won't work as I have to pass the content before the link is clicked otherwise google does not returns it back as the params. Anyway a little modification with your code did the job.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwalGreat! What was the modification?